# Cómo detener el código PHP si la condición no se cumple

Tags: php

Necesito ayuda con php:

Estoy desarrollando cierta aplicación web con la que necesito que se cumpla determinada condición para que se ejecute el resto del código. Por ahora tengo desarrollado lo siguiente, aunque me resulta muy engorroso de ver:

```
if ($message != 'Mensaje') {

    echo '¡El mensaje está mal escrito!';

} else {

    echo '¡El texto del mensaje es correcto!';

    // Aquí hay otras 800 líneas de código.

}
```

Como se puede ver en la anotación, hay mucho código en el `else`. Cuando se acumulan este tipo de sentencias el código se va volviendo cada vez más y más "sucio", cosa que no me interesa.

¿Hay alguna forma de no tener que utilizar `else`? Es decir:

```
if ($message != 'Mensaje') {

    echo '¡El mensaje está mal escrito!';
    
    // Sentencia que pone fin al código, tal y como lo hace un require; cuando suelta un error.

}

echo '¡El texto del mensaje es correcto!';

// Aquí hay otras 800 líneas de código.
```

De esta manera, el primer código y el segundo darían los mismos resultados con la excepción de que el segundo es mucho más limpio que el primero. Hasta ahora había buscado información acerca de `require`, pero por lo visto solo funciona si se trata de comprobar la existencia de ciertos archivos. ¿Existe una forma de obtener los mismos resultados que con `require` al utilizar variables?

Un saludo y buena programación.

Comment: Creo que lo que necesitas es el comando "exit", simplemente antes del } del else, añade exit(); (https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exit.php) y ya puedes quitar el else porque si entra en el if, no seguirá ejecutando.

Comment: Como te ha indicado @track3r, tal como lo haces usa exit. Por cierto, cuando se trata de errores se suele usar `die()`, exit se usa normalmente cuando no es un error Otra opción es usar programación orientada a objetos y devolver siempre un valor, aunque sea un mensaje de error, así podrías usar `if($message != "Mensaje") return "El mensaje está mal escrito);`y el código no continuaría a partir de ese return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer perfectamente pero en vez de usar un `echo` utiliza un `return`, pero debes tener la validación dentro de una función.

***return** devuelve el control del programa al módulo que lo invoca. La ejecución vuelve a la siguiente expresión después del módulo que lo invoca.*

*Si se llama desde una función, la sentencia return inmediatamente termina la ejecución de la función actual, y devuelve su argumento como el valor de la llamada a la función. return también termina la ejecución de una sentencia eval() o un archivo de script.*

Es decir lo debes hacer de estam manera:

```
function validarMensaje($message) {

    if ($message != 'Mensaje') {
        
         return '¡El mensaje está mal escrito!';      
     }
        
         return '¡El texto del mensaje es correcto!';
 }

echo validarMensaje('Mensaje') //output: ¡El texto del mensaje es correcto!
```

Ahora bien, si deseas hacerlo con un echo, cosa que no recomiendo, entonces  puedes colocar un `exit()` en el lugar donde quieres que la ejecución del script se detenga.

*exit — Imprime un mensaje y termina el script actual*

```
exit ([ string $status ] ) : void
exit ( int $status ) : void
```

*Finaliza la ejecución del script. Funciones shutdown y Objectos destructores siempre serán ejecutados incluso si se llama a la función exit.*

*Exit es una construcción de lenguaje y puede ser llamada sin paréntesis si no se le pasa status.*

Ahora bien si lo que quieres es reutilizar código te recomiendo trabajar con clases y objetos, o al menos con una función que te retorne `true` o `false` dependiendo lo que se cumpla.

**Fuente:** https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exit.php

**Fuente:** https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.return.php